# How to add background image to docx document through apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

How i can add background image to docx document through Apache POI or other java framework.
I would like have some xml block, where defined background, in result document like that

```
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
<w:background w:color="FFFFFF">
    <v:background id="_x0000_s1025" o:bwmode="white" o:targetscreensize="1024,768">
        <v:fill r:id="rId2" o:title="Alien 1" recolor="t" type="frame"/>
    </v:background>
</w:background>
<w:body>
      .....
</w:body></w:document>
```

Comment: Do you know where you want to put that in the file? If so, should be fairly easy to grab the low level CT object and add it in. If you clarify where in the doc you want it, it'll be easy to show you how to do that

Comment: I added a template resulting document, could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to add a background element to the root of the document, you'll need to do something like:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("test.docx"));
if (doc.getDocument().getBackground() == null) {
   doc.getDocument.addNewBackground();
};

CTBackground bkgnd = doc.getDocument().getBackground();
bkgnd.setColor("FFFFFF");
```

Now, to add your new background into the backgrounds list, which is in a different namespace, it's a bit trickier. We'd do something like:

```
String xml = 
  "<v:background id=\"_x0000_s1025\" o:bwmode=\"white\" o:targetscreensize=\"1024,768\">" +
  "<v:fill r:id=\"rId2\" o:title=\"Alien 1\" recolor=\"t\" type=\"frame\"/>" +
  "</v:background>";
bkgnd.set(XmlToken.Factory.parse(xml));
```

If you look in something like [XWPFRun](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.java) you'll see an example of adding in xml from a different namespace. Were it all in the .docx namespace you could do it all with the CT Objects, but sadly yours is a complicated case...

If the manual XML stuff is a bit fiddly for you, try using POI to process a file with that added in by Word, and play around with the `CTBackground` object. That might let you work out the xmlbeans object for the inner `v:background` xml, which would offer up a simpler way of doing it. If you get it working, send in [patch to POI](http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html)!

Comment: Ok, thank you, i will try play around with the CTBackground, if this works out, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Using docx4j's online code generator:

**Method 1**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import org.docx4j.vml.CTBackground;
import org.docx4j.vml.CTFill;
import org.docx4j.wml.CTBackground;


public class Foo { 
public CTBackground createBackground() {

org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory wmlObjectFactory = new org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory();

CTBackground background = wmlObjectFactory.createCTBackground(); 
    background.setColor( "FFFFFF"); 
org.docx4j.vml.ObjectFactory vmlObjectFactory = new org.docx4j.vml.ObjectFactory();
    // Create object for background (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
    CTBackground background2 = vmlObjectFactory.createCTBackground(); 
    JAXBElement<org.docx4j.vml.CTBackground> backgroundWrapped = vmlObjectFactory.createBackground(background2); 
    background.getAnyAndAny().add( backgroundWrapped); 
        background2.setTargetscreensize( "1024,768"); 
        background2.setVmlId( "_x0000_s1025"); 
        background2.setBwmode(org.docx4j.vml.officedrawing.STBWMode.WHITE);
        // Create object for fill
        CTFill fill = vmlObjectFactory.createCTFill(); 
        background2.setFill(fill); 
            fill.setTitle( "Alien 1"); 
            fill.setId( "rId5"); 
            fill.setType(org.docx4j.vml.STFillType.FRAME);
            fill.setRecolor(org.docx4j.vml.STTrueFalse.T);

return background;
}
}
```

**Method 2**

```
    String openXML = "<w:background w:color=\"FFFFFF\" xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\">
                + "<v:background id=\"_x0000_s1025\" o:bwmode=\"white\" o:targetscreensize=\"1024,768\">
                      + "<v:fill o:title=\"Alien 1\" r:id=\"rId5\" recolor=\"t\" type=\"frame\"/>"

                +"</v:background>"

          +"</w:background>";
CTBackground background = (CTBackground)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(openXML);
```

Comment: Note that a background image is different to a picture watermark.  The latter is probably what you want. See docx4j samples BackgroundImage and WatermarkPicture respectively.